# Не отображается шкала в zabbix

Tags: zabbix

убунту 16.04 php 5.6
Установил последний заббикс, решил потестировать его.
Сначала была проблема с импортом скрипта в базу заббикса, но изменил кодировку на базе и все импортировалась. Но столкнулся с не отображением шкалы и items.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В шаблонах все прописано, все есть, но не отображается.
С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Пустая папка шрифтов, Zabbix ожидает там свой дефолтный шрифт:
/usr/share/zabbix/fonts/graphfont.ttf

Только что решил для Zabbix 3.4 на Debian 9 так:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-dejavu-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure zabbix-frontend-php
```

> update-alternatives: using
>   /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf to provide
>   /usr/share/zabbix/fonts/graphfont.ttf (zabbix-frontend-font) in auto
>   mode